# How can I avoid merging cells in multi-level column headers when saving to excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, output, export-to-excel

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to output a pandas dataframe into excel. This dataframe has multiindexing for both columns and rows. To have an idea of the structure of this dataframe I will attach some column indexes (since it is very long) and the row indexes on the first and second pictures respectively. As you can see, there appear some merged cells but this is undesired. You would say that i can use the option:

```
df.to_excel('output.csv', merge_cells=False)
```

But this will concatenate the columns in format like this: 2024.1.2, 2024.1.3, 2024.1.4, etc. In a single column level (instead of having 3 column levels like right now, which are "2024" first level, "1" second level, ["2", "3", "4"] third level). I want to keep the three levels but the 2024 to be reapeated for each colum and not to be a merged cell.

I also tried

```
df.T.reset_index().T
```

but this doesn't solve my problem since then the columns will be part of the table and this is also not desired since it will aquire the table formating I'm giving, and won't be in bold and centered format like the header they should be.

I was expecting an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Now is clarified

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that in time someone will point out the options I missed, something like `sparsify=False` as in the case of [DataFrame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=sparsify). In the meantime, I suggest this way of solving the problem.

We can put unique numbers at the very top level to force a writer distinguish each column and write lower levels without merging. Let's see how it works:

```
from pandas import MultiIndex, DataFrame, ExcelWriter

columns = MultiIndex.from_product([[2024],[*'AB'],[*'xy']])
data = [[*range(columns.size)]]
df = DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

#   2024         
#      A     B   
#      x  y  x  y
# 0    0  1  2  3

# put a unique number at the top of each columns
enum_cols = MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [range(df.columns.size), *zip(*df.columns)]
)

# prepare a writer for removing column number at the end
file, sheet = 'test_multicolumn.xlsx', 'Sheet1'
writer = ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')

# replace columns with their numbered version and save to excel
df.set_axis(enum_cols, axis='columns').to_excel(writer, sheet)

# remove the level of column numbers, save and close
writer.sheets[sheet].delete_rows(1)
writer.close()
```

Now data are saved with headers in each columns. Note that a trick with `style.hide(axis='columns', level=0)` is ignored by `to_excel`, so we need a writer to delete an upper row with numbers (or we remove it manually later in Excel).

[image: screenshot of excel table]